# In SQL Server, how do I save the results of a query to a txt file?

Tags: sql-server, export

In SQL Server, how do I export the results of a query to a txt file. I tried tools>options>results to file. But this appears to have saved the Messages the query generated instead of the Results the query generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Options:

- Use sqlcmd at the command line to execute your SQL statement; the results will arrive as text and can be trivially saved.

  - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd
- Use bcp at the command line to execute your SQL statement with the "queryout" parameter.
- Use SSMS to grid as you are, right-click the upper left cell of the results pane and use the Save Results As... option
- Use SSMS to file; this will of course save the file on the machine SSMS is running on.  Tools->Options->Results to file is where you set options like delimiter, maximum size, and so on.  Instead, you want Query->Results To->Results to File or Ctrl-Shift-F (by default)
- Other non-SQL ways like Powershell or any application language or MS Access or Excel with a DSN data source or SSIS or many many many other ways.

Answer (score 1):

A manual way of achieving it is to `CRTL+T` on your SSMS to enable the option **Results to Text**. Execute your query and right click the `Results > Save results as > Save as Type > All Files` and name your file something.txt.

[image: Result to Text option]

Comment: Thanks for the answers Ronaldo. It's not working though, perhaps because I am accessing SQL Server through a VDI? Control T does not illicit anything, and I tried to save to text via Tools>Options>Results to Text, but that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I just ran SELECT * FROM SYSDATABASES successfully. It did something. Not sure what.

Comment: @Jimbo your problem is not related to using a VDI. That query `SELECT * FROM SYSDATABASES` was just an example of a query to have a result to print and post on my answer. What version of SSMS (Management Studio) are you using? Did you hit `CTRL+T` after you had a tab open to run a query?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not restricted only to SSMS, you can use Powershell

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance MyInstance -Database MyDB -Query "SELECT * FROM Mytable" | Export-CSV "C:\MyResults.csv"`